# Stuck with DNX reference issue in ASP.NET 5/VS2015

Tags: asp.net, powershell, visual-studio-2015, asp.net-core, dnx

[image: DNX Reference Issue]

This is the Error which I am getting and i have installed with Powershell 3.0 Kindly help me with the solution. Not sure how do overcome this issue. I have tried to upgrade dnvm but nothing works out :(

```
PATH=.\node_modules\.bin;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\Common7\IDE\Extensions\Microsoft\Web Tools\External;%PATH%;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\Common7\IDE\Extensions\Microsoft\Web Tools\External\git
C:\Users\Selva\.dnx\runtimes\dnx-clr-win-x86.1.0.0-beta8\bin\dnx.exe "C:\Users\Selva\.dnx\runtimes\dnx-clr-win-x86.1.0.0-beta8\bin\lib\Microsoft.DNX.PackageManager\Microsoft.DNX.PackageManager.dll" restore "C:\Projects\MVA\src\MVA" -s "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Web Tools\DNU"
System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.DNX.PackageManager' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.
File name: 'Microsoft.DNX.PackageManager'
   at System.Reflection.RuntimeAssembly._nLoad(AssemblyName fileName, String codeBase, Evidence assemblySecurity, RuntimeAssembly locationHint, StackCrawlMark& stackMark, IntPtr pPrivHostBinder, Boolean throwOnFileNotFound, Boolean forIntrospection, Boolean suppressSecurityChecks)
   at System.Reflection.RuntimeAssembly.nLoad(AssemblyName fileName, String codeBase, Evidence assemblySecurity, RuntimeAssembly locationHint, StackCrawlMark& stackMark, IntPtr pPrivHostBinder, Boolean throwOnFileNotFound, Boolean forIntrospection, Boolean suppressSecurityChecks)
   at System.Reflection.RuntimeAssembly.InternalLoadAssemblyName(AssemblyName assemblyRef, Evidence assemblySecurity, RuntimeAssembly reqAssembly, StackCrawlMark& stackMark, IntPtr pPrivHostBinder, Boolean throwOnFileNotFound, Boolean forIntrospection, Boolean suppressSecurityChecks)
   at System.Reflection.Assembly.Load(AssemblyName assemblyRef)
   at Microsoft.Dnx.Runtime.Loader.LoadContext.Load(AssemblyName assemblyName)
   at Microsoft.Dnx.Host.Bootstrapper.RunAsync(List`1 args, IRuntimeEnvironment env, String appBase, FrameworkName targetFramework)
   at Microsoft.Dnx.Host.RuntimeBootstrapper.ExecuteAsync(String[] args, BootstrapperContext bootstrapperContext)
   at Microsoft.Dnx.Host.RuntimeBootstrapper.Execute(String[] args, BootstrapperContext bootstrapperContext)
WRN: Assembly binding logging is turned OFF.
To enable assembly bind failure logging, set the registry value [HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Fusion!EnableLog] (DWORD) to 1.
Note: There is some performance penalty associated with assembly bind failure logging.
To turn this feature off, remove the registry value [HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Fusion!EnableLog].
PATH=.\node_modules\.bin;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\Common7\IDE\Extensions\Microsoft\Web Tools\External;%PATH%;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\Common7\IDE\Extensions\Microsoft\Web Tools\External\git
C:\Users\Selva\.dnx\runtimes\dnx-clr-win-x86.1.0.0-beta8\bin\dnx.exe "C:\Users\Selva\.dnx\runtimes\dnx-clr-win-x86.1.0.0-beta8\bin\lib\Microsoft.DNX.PackageManager\Microsoft.DNX.PackageManager.dll" restore "C:\Projects\MVA\src\MVA" -f "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Web Tools\DNU"
System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.DNX.PackageManager' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.
File name: 'Microsoft.DNX.PackageManager'
   at System.Reflection.RuntimeAssembly._nLoad(AssemblyName fileName, String codeBase, Evidence assemblySecurity, RuntimeAssembly locationHint, StackCrawlMark& stackMark, IntPtr pPrivHostBinder, Boolean throwOnFileNotFound, Boolean forIntrospection, Boolean suppressSecurityChecks)
   at System.Reflection.RuntimeAssembly.nLoad(AssemblyName fileName, String codeBase, Evidence assemblySecurity, RuntimeAssembly locationHint, StackCrawlMark& stackMark, IntPtr pPrivHostBinder, Boolean throwOnFileNotFound, Boolean forIntrospection, Boolean suppressSecurityChecks)
   at System.Reflection.RuntimeAssembly.InternalLoadAssemblyName(AssemblyName assemblyRef, Evidence assemblySecurity, RuntimeAssembly reqAssembly, StackCrawlMark& stackMark, IntPtr pPrivHostBinder, Boolean throwOnFileNotFound, Boolean forIntrospection, Boolean suppressSecurityChecks)
   at System.Reflection.Assembly.Load(AssemblyName assemblyRef)
   at Microsoft.Dnx.Runtime.Loader.LoadContext.Load(AssemblyName assemblyName)
   at Microsoft.Dnx.Host.Bootstrapper.RunAsync(List`1 args, IRuntimeEnvironment env, String appBase, FrameworkName targetFramework)
   at Microsoft.Dnx.Host.RuntimeBootstrapper.ExecuteAsync(String[] args, BootstrapperContext bootstrapperContext)
   at Microsoft.Dnx.Host.RuntimeBootstrapper.Execute(String[] args, BootstrapperContext bootstrapperContext)
WRN: Assembly binding logging is turned OFF.
To enable assembly bind failure logging, set the registry value [HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Fusion!EnableLog] (DWORD) to 1.
Note: There is some performance penalty associated with assembly bind failure logging.
To turn this feature off, remove the registry value [HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Fusion!EnableLog].
PATH=.\node_modules\.bin;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\Common7\IDE\Extensions\Microsoft\Web Tools\External;%PATH%;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\Common7\IDE\Extensions\Microsoft\Web Tools\External\git
C:\Users\Selva\.dnx\runtimes\dnx-clr-win-x86.1.0.0-beta8\bin\dnx.exe "C:\Users\Selva\.dnx\runtimes\dnx-clr-win-x86.1.0.0-beta8\bin\lib\Microsoft.DNX.PackageManager\Microsoft.DNX.PackageManager.dll" restore "C:\Projects\MVA\src\MVA" -f "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Web Tools\DNU"
System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.DNX.PackageManager' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.
File name: 'Microsoft.DNX.PackageManager'
   at System.Reflection.RuntimeAssembly._nLoad(AssemblyName fileName, String codeBase, Evidence assemblySecurity, RuntimeAssembly locationHint, StackCrawlMark& stackMark, IntPtr pPrivHostBinder, Boolean throwOnFileNotFound, Boolean forIntrospection, Boolean suppressSecurityChecks)
   at System.Reflection.RuntimeAssembly.nLoad(AssemblyName fileName, String codeBase, Evidence assemblySecurity, RuntimeAssembly locationHint, StackCrawlMark& stackMark, IntPtr pPrivHostBinder, Boolean throwOnFileNotFound, Boolean forIntrospection, Boolean suppressSecurityChecks)
   at System.Reflection.RuntimeAssembly.InternalLoadAssemblyName(AssemblyName assemblyRef, Evidence assemblySecurity, RuntimeAssembly reqAssembly, StackCrawlMark& stackMark, IntPtr pPrivHostBinder, Boolean throwOnFileNotFound, Boolean forIntrospection, Boolean suppressSecurityChecks)
   at System.Reflection.Assembly.Load(AssemblyName assemblyRef)
   at Microsoft.Dnx.Runtime.Loader.LoadContext.Load(AssemblyName assemblyName)
   at Microsoft.Dnx.Host.Bootstrapper.RunAsync(List`1 args, IRuntimeEnvironment env, String appBase, FrameworkName targetFramework)
   at Microsoft.Dnx.Host.RuntimeBootstrapper.ExecuteAsync(String[] args, BootstrapperContext bootstrapperContext)
   at Microsoft.Dnx.Host.RuntimeBootstrapper.Execute(String[] args, BootstrapperContext bootstrapperContext)
WRN: Assembly binding logging is turned OFF.
To enable assembly bind failure logging, set the registry value [HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Fusion!EnableLog] (DWORD) to 1.
Note: There is some performance penalty associated with assembly bind failure logging.
To turn this feature off, remove the registry value [HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Fusion!EnableLog].
```

My Project.Json goes like below

```
{
  "webroot": "wwwroot",
  "userSecretsId": "aspnet5*************************************",
  "version": "1.0.0-*",

  "dependencies": {
    "EntityFramework.SqlServer": "7.0.0-beta5",
    "EntityFramework.Commands": "7.0.0-beta5",
    "Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc": "6.0.0-beta5",
    "Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc.TagHelpers": "6.0.0-beta5",
    "Microsoft.AspNet.Authentication.Cookies": "1.0.0-beta5",
    "Microsoft.AspNet.Authentication.Facebook": "1.0.0-beta5",
    "Microsoft.AspNet.Authentication.Google": "1.0.0-beta5",
    "Microsoft.AspNet.Authentication.MicrosoftAccount": "1.0.0-beta5",
    "Microsoft.AspNet.Authentication.Twitter": "1.0.0-beta5",
    "Microsoft.AspNet.Diagnostics": "1.0.0-beta5",
    "Microsoft.AspNet.Diagnostics.Entity": "7.0.0-beta5",
    "Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.EntityFramework": "3.0.0-beta5",
    "Microsoft.AspNet.Server.IIS": "1.0.0-beta5",
    "Microsoft.AspNet.Server.WebListener": "1.0.0-beta5",
    "Microsoft.AspNet.StaticFiles": "1.0.0-beta5",
    "Microsoft.AspNet.Tooling.Razor": "1.0.0-beta5",
    "Microsoft.Framework.Configuration.Abstractions": "1.0.0-beta5",
    "Microsoft.Framework.Configuration.Json": "1.0.0-beta5",
    "Microsoft.Framework.Configuration.UserSecrets": "1.0.0-beta5",
    "Microsoft.Framework.Logging": "1.0.0-beta5",
    "Microsoft.Framework.Logging.Console": "1.0.0-beta5",
    "Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.BrowserLink.Loader": "14.0.0-beta5"
  },

  "commands": {
    "web": "Microsoft.AspNet.Hosting --config hosting.ini",
    "ef": "EntityFramework.Commands"
  },

  "frameworks": {
    "dnx451": { },
    "dnxcore50": { }
  },

  "exclude": [
    "wwwroot",
    "node_modules",
    "bower_components"
  ],
  "publishExclude": [
    "node_modules",
    "bower_components",
    "**.xproj",
    "**.user",
    "**.vspscc"
  ],
  "scripts": {
    "prepublish": [ "npm install", "bower install", "gulp clean", "gulp min" ]
  }
}
```

Comment: If you could add your `project.json`, it would help us.

Answer (score 2):

I'm under the impression that you have a version mismatch (older project with newer version of the framework).

First, make sure that you have the [`beta8` tooling](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=49442) installed. Then, go in your project properties and make sure to change the target runtime to `beta8`.

Finally, check your `project.json` to ensure that you are not left with pre-`beta8` packages.

In your `project.json`, ensure to remove any reference to `beta5` and replace them by `beta8`. Some packages were renamed and some were merged so you might not be able to replace everything.

If you are running with IIS and dependes on `Microsoft.AspNet.Server.IIS`, make sure to add `app.RunIISPipeline();` on your `Startup.cs/Configure()` method.

Comment: And as mentioned, you have a whole bunch of old packages. Replace `beta5` by `beta8`. Please be aware that some packages were renamed and might not work.

Comment: I am not seeing any package to upgrade when i opened my Nuget package manager. All of my packages are uptodate.

Comment: System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.DNX.PackageManager' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.
1>  File name: 'Microsoft.DNX.PackageManager'

Comment: Your `project.json` have dependencies like this: `"EntityFramework.SqlServer": "7.0.0-beta5",`. See this `beta5` there? That comes from the templates. Do a find/replace to get to the version you want to run.

Answer (score 1):

This issue appears to have been fixed in a newer release of ASP.net, [which is available here.](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/aspnet/announcing-availability-of-asp-net-5-beta-6/)

Based [on this discussion](https://github.com/aspnet/Announcements/issues/44) from GitHub

Comment: He's running `beta8`.

Comment: Yes. I am running beta 8.

Comment: Change to beta5 - click on any project->Properties->Application choose beta5. Using `dnvm use 1.0.0-beta5` won't help you. There were breaking changes between these two releases.

Comment: I have changed to beta5. But getting the same error.

System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.DNX.PackageManager' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.
1>  File name: 'Microsoft.DNX.PackageManager'

Answer (score 1):

You need to not only install beta 8, but also the tooling for visual studio. the download can be found [here](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=49442). Specifically, you need to download and install WebToolsExtensionsVS14.msi